# Redis CLI seems to hang forever on Windows Bash

Tags: windows, redis, command-line-interface

I am working with the `3.2.100` Redis for Windows release, whose portable code I downloaded from [this GitHub page](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases).
I can successfully start the Redis server from a bash using `./redis-server`, which generates this output:

```
[12712] 18 Feb 17:54:29.328 # Server started, Redis version 3.2.100
[12712] 18 Feb 17:54:29.328 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
[12712] 18 Feb 17:54:29.328 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
```

From the `.conf` files I can see that `127.0.0.1` is being bound as the IP address.  Yet, when I open another bash window and try to open a CLI connection, it just hangs:

```
./redis-cli
```

There is no output from the above, but rather the bash console just advances to the next line, and sits there.

For background, I am working in a fairly controlled environment, behind a proxy.  But, I don't see how that would affect something entirely on my local machine.  The ultimate goal would be to use Redis from a Java project, but getting things to work from the command line seems like a good prerequisite.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after posting this question, on a lark, I decided to open the Windows command prompt just to see what would happen with `redis-cli`.  To my surprise, it appears to be working from the prompt:

```
C:\...\Redis-x64-3.2.100>redis-cli.exe
127.0.0.1:6379> PING
PONG
127.0.0.1:6379> SET blah 1
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> EXPIRE key 60
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> TYPE blah
string
127.0.0.1:6379> MGET blah
1) "1"
127.0.0.1:6379> MGET blah
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

I expired a key, just to make sure that some functionality is working as expected.

The moral of the story here is to maybe avoid the Bash when using Redis on Windows.  I was able to start the server without issues, but the CLI tool did not seem to work.

So, one answer to my question is to use the Windows command prompt for the `redis-cli` tool.